# Ajax callback returns value but wrapper isn't filled

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm stuck because whatever I do my wrapper is never filled with my callback, any idea ?

```
  $form['show_liste_produits'] = array(
   '#type' => 'button',
   //'#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'return (false);'),
   '#value' => t('Lister les produits'),
   '#name'  => 'awesome-button',
   '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'stockerAll',
      'wrapper' => 'listeProduits',
      'method'   => 'replace',
      'effect'   => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  $form['listeProduits'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => array('listeProduits'),
    ),
  );

function stockerAll($form, $form_state){
 return 'test';
}
```

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT:**
In fact in the network tab I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6BzY.png), maybe the selector isn't working ?
Moreover, my empty container isn't displayed after page load actually, maybe is it the source of the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code into the code below:

```
 $form['show_liste_produits'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',   
     '#value' => t('Lister les produits'),   
     '#ajax' => array(
         'callback' => 'stockerAll',
         'wrapper' => 'listeProduits',      
     ),
);

$form['listeProduits'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('id'=> 'listeProduits'),         
);
```

If it doesnt work,make sure first if `stockerAll` is called. Insert `watchdog('test','test');` in `the stockerAll` function . After doing so, run the program, check your drupal database, particularly the `watchdog` table and check whether 'test' is in the latest log.

```
function stockerAll($form, $form_state){
    watchdog('test','test');
    return 'test';
}
```

If `stockerAll` is called, clear cache of the browser to make sure the updated code is the one executing. Else, there's something wrong with the way you invoke your function.

Comment: Your code didn't solve the problem (but it was a good idea).  
In fact in the network tab I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/o4JJRfa.png), maybe the selector isn't working ?  
Moreover, my empty container isn't displayed after page load actually, maybe is it the source of the problem ?

Comment: @Germain67 --> Did you found the 'test' message in the watchdog table in the drupal database?

Comment: --> Yes it is in the watchdog table (and the function returned something as you can see on the picture), so the callback is technically working.

Comment: I tried my code above and it's working with me. You must display your code completely for reader's better comprehension.

Comment: I finally found what was wrong, my ajax callback was in conflict with another event in my javascript file, thank you for you help :)